# How can use Genymotion with Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

Can i use genymotion for community license? Genymotion must have usb connection type.Appears upgrade license message. I have also tried with virtual   connection type..

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure you first start the Genymotion emulator and make sure you use USB connection, set up your profile with the correct device then click on Device Emulator button.

[Detailed Instructions](https://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/project/genymotion/)

Comment: Thanks.I have read  the instructions but when i use usb connection appears this message  http://i.imgur.com/SPBy9eD.png?1

Comment: Yes, you are only allowed 10 times to use the USB option because using Genymotion acts like you have a physical device. So, its telling you 5 more  times to use the USB option. You can press yes to continue.  Or, you can upgrade and pay the $100 for individual version and you will not see that screen anymore. I payed the $100 because its a great product and we should support. I also would like to say to smartface.io to also allow us to buy the University Package at a separate price point.